# Why doesn't the compiler report an error when a variable not declared as mutable is modified?

Tags: variables, syntax, compilation, rust, mutable

I installed Rust 1.13 and tried:

```
fn main() {
    let x: u32;
    x = 10; // no error?
}
```

When I compiled this file there's some warnings, but there's no error. As I'm not declaring `x` as `mut`, shouldn't `x = 10;` cause an error?

Comment: That's deferred initialization, not mutation.

Comment: Rust 1.16 is the current version of Rust, and 1.17 should be released in a few weeks. It's worth it to stay current.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you have written is identical to:

```
let x: u32 = 10;
```

The compiler will not permit you to mutate it thereafter:

```
let x: u32;
x = 10;
x = 0; // Error: re-assignment of immutable variable `x`
```

Note that it is a compiler error if you try to use an uninitialized variable:

```
let x: u32;
println!("{}", x); // Error: use of possibly uninitialized variable: `x`
```

This feature can be pretty useful if you want to initialize the variable differently based on runtime conditions. A naive example:

```
let x: u32;
if condition {
    x = 1;   
} else if other_condition {
    x = 10;
} else {
    x = 100;
}
```

But still it will still be an error if there is a *possibility* that it isn't initialized:

```
let x: u32;
if condition {
    x = 1;   
} else if other_condition {
    x = 10;
} // no else
println!("{:?}", x); // Error: use of possibly uninitialized variable: `x`
```

Comment: Idiomatic rust would more likely use expression-oriented syntax here: `let x = if condition { 1 } else if other_condition { 10 } else { 100 };`. There is no need for deferred initialization in these examples.

Comment: @MatthieuM. That's true. But if there were different side-effects inside some of the conditional branches, it would look odd. In that case, I think this form would be more idiomatic.

Answer (score 12):

As mentioned, this is not mutation, but deferred initialization:

- mutation is about changing the value of an existing variable,
- deferred initialization is about declaring a variable at one point, and initializing it later.

The Rust compiler tracks whether a variable has a value at compile-time, so unlike C there is no risk of accidentally using an uninitialized variable (or unlike C++, a variable that was moved from).

---

The most important reason for using deferred initialization is **scope**.

```
fn main() {
    let x;
    let mut v = vec!();

    {
        x = 2;
        v.push(&x);
    }

    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

In Rust, the borrow-checker will validate that a reference cannot outlive the value it refers to, preventing dangling references.

This means that `v.push(&x)` requires that `x` lives longer than `v`, and therefore be declared *before* `v`.

The need for it does not crop up often, but when it does other solutions would require run-time checks.