# Non-mut variables is mutable leading to crash

Tags: rust

I ran across a weird case where Rust was telling me that I didn't need `mut` on a variable, even though I was clearly mutating it! After some fiddling around I managed to get the following code to compile which just looks broken.

```rust
fn main() {
    let x: u32;
    loop {
        match 1 {
            1 => {}
            _ => {
                x = 5;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    dbg!(x);
}
```

Running it ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0867a5383d5da0b92d63c143fdbc1a1a)) results in some kind of crash. What's going on here? Is this a compiler bug? I tried it on nightly and it still times out.

Comment: It's an infinite loop, which doesn't have anything to do with the initialization of `x`.

Comment: The infinite loop obscures your real question which I think is about [deferred initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43519766/why-doesnt-the-compiler-report-an-error-when-a-variable-not-declared-as-mutable/43520485#43520485)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This also compiles:

```
let x: u32;

if false {
    x = 5;
}
```

As well as:

```
let x: u32;
x = 5;
```

As @trentcl mentions, this is deferred initialization, which is why it is accepted.